# Phonegap 3.6.3 whitelisting ignored on android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, whitelist

I am testing with PhoneGap. I have a problem that whitleisting domains is completely ignored on Android.
in config.xml I add the following line, so I only should have access to that Domain.

```
<access origin="http://test12345test.com"/>
```

But when I run the app I can access every website. I use the window.location to load external content:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    window.location = "https://www.google.com";
}
```

Google loads without any problem. Why is whitelisting not working? 
For building the app I use PhoneGap Build service

specs:
Android 4.3
Phonegap 3.6.3
Building apps PhoneGap Build service

Comment: have you tried `<access origin="test12345test.com"/>` instead of `<access origin="http://test12345test.com"/>`?

Comment: This gives the same result have tried `<access origin="test12345test.com"/>`  and `<access />` in all cases google.com is loaded, so the whitelist is ignored. I don't know why but this is not secure. here are the settings in the .apk after build from phonegap build service: res/xml/config.xml `s u b d o m a i n s    t e s t 1 2 3 4 5 t e s t . c o m    h t t p : / / d e b u g . b u i l d . p h o n e g a p . c o m    h t t p : / / 1 2 7 . 0 . 0 . 1 *`